# Current controller and action in body class?

Tags: class, controller, yii2, action

I need to change layout style according with current controller and action.

How can you add current controller and action in body class?

Answer (score 0):

You can add current controller and action in your body class with this simple code.

```
<body class="<?php
        echo 'co-'.Yii::$app->controller->id. ' ac-' .Yii::$app->controller->module->requestedAction->id;
    ?>">
```

Of course you can change 'co-' and 'ac-' strings as you like ('controller-' and 'action-' for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the current controller and action in main layout:

```
$controller = Yii::$app->controller;
$action = $controller->action->id;

<body class="<?= $controller.' '. $action ?>" >
....
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this

```
<?php
$route = Yii::$app->controller->route;
?>
<body class="page-<?= str_replace('/', '-', $route) ?>">
```

`$route = Yii::$app->controller->route;` will return something like `site/index` so you just need to replace the `/` character with `-`

Answer (score 0):

You can change layout style according to Action or Controller:

```
// action
if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'NameAction') {
  # code here 
  $this->registerCssFile("@web/..."); // Or whatever you need
}

// controller
if (Yii::$app->controller->id == 'NameController') {
  # code here ...
}
```